# PlaceAutoCompleteFragment NullPointerException when accessing via findFragmentById

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

The following XML shows I do have the `fragment` added. 
It is a lot, but you can find the `fragment` at the bottom. The other UI elements are irrelevant, I just included them for the sake of completeness.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="7">
    <EditText
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Event name"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fromLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="From:"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fromDate"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2017.01.01"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            />
        <EditText
            android:text="00:00"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/fromTime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="To:"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/toDate"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2017.01.01"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            />
        <EditText
            android:text="00:00"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/toTime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Description"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitEvent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit event"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_rowSpan="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:id="@+id/friendsList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="0.6"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        >
    </FrameLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="7"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1.6"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
    />
</GridLayout>
```

And I have the `Activity` file, whose `onCreare` contains this code **AFTER** the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);`

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment =
            (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
   @Override
   public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
       Log.i("PLACE",  place.getName().toString());
   }

   @Override
   public void onError(Status status) {
       Log.i("PLACE", "ERROR WHEN AUTO COMPLETE PLACE");
   }
});
```

The problem is, the `setOnPlaceSelectedListener` gives me the `NullPointerException` all the time, and says I'm trying to set the listener to a `null` object. I need to use the Google Places in a fragment.

Note, for smaller screens the `Activity` version starts alright. The problem is only with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create class which extends fragment, override onCreateView method and inflate your fragment layout (place_autocomplete_fragment) in that method. Then create object of that class and only then you can set listener.

```
class FragmentClass extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_autocomplete_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

then create FragmentClass object and set desired listeners.